# Throws Assertion error

Tags: javascript, gulp, bootstrap-4

Searching via same question couldn't solve.
I am working on the bootstrap 4 installation with the help of this guy's https://coursetro.com/posts/code/130/Learn-Bootstrap-4-Final-in-2018-with-our-Free-Crash-Course  tutorial.

When followed the same: I see

Gulp: error in console, assert.js:90 throw new assert.AssertionError

```
 AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: Task function must be specified
    at Gulp.set [as _setTask] (C:\Users\dc\Projects\main-pro
ject\bs4\node_modules\undertaker\lib\set-task.js:10:3)
    at Gulp.task (C:\Users\dc\Projects\main-project\bs4\node
_modules\undertaker\lib\task.js:13:8)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\dc\Projects\main-project
\bs4\gulpfile.js:21:6)
    at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
```

and this is my gulpfile.js

```
    var gulp        = require('gulp');
var browserSync = require('browser-sync').create();
var sass        = require('gulp-sass');

// Compile sass into CSS & auto-inject into browsers
gulp.task('sass', function() {
    return gulp.src(['node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss', 'src/scss/*.scss'])
        .pipe(sass())
        .pipe(gulp.dest("src/css"))
        .pipe(browserSync.stream());
});

// Move the javascript files into our /src/js folder
gulp.task('js', function() {
    return gulp.src(['node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js', 'node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js', 'node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js'])
        .pipe(gulp.dest("src/js"))
        .pipe(browserSync.stream());
});

// Static Server + watching scss/html files
gulp.task('serve', ['sass'], function() {

    browserSync.init({
        server: "./src"
    });

    gulp.watch(['node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss', 'src/scss/*.scss'], ['sass']);
    gulp.watch("src/*.html").on('change', browserSync.reload);
});

gulp.task('default', ['js','serve']);
```

Comment: Topic should be changed to "GULP 4 Throws Assertion error : Task function must be specified"

Answer (score 0):

Late reply, but maybe this still helps. The tutorial uses gulp v.3 and you have installed v.4. New version requires Task function to be specified. Short answer is to change tasks like:

```
gulp.task('serve', ['js','serve'], function() {...});
```

to

```
gulp.task('start', gulp.parallel(['js','serve'], function () {...}));
```

Long answer requires reading this page https://fettblog.eu/gulp-4-parallel-and-series/

Comment: The gulp.watch…['sass'] line needs to be changed as well.  You should edit your answer to include these comments.